# Authentication context not auditing success event

Tags: keycloak, java-11

I use keycloak to reset a user's password through a custom flow.
The flow works for resetting the password and logging/auditing error events.
But the `context.success()` doesn't log events in `EVENT_ENTITY`. I tried changing the event type to try and find the root cause using
 `context.getEvent().event(EventType.SEND_RESET_PASSWORD_ERROR); // for eg. context.success();`

I am not sure what the problem is, or fail to understand what is different from setting a success and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was me missing a call to send the event on success.

on error on `context.getEvent().error(..)` which call `EventBuilder.send()` internally. I had to use `context.getEvent().sucess()` to save the event on success.